# how to display captcha image in imageView

Tags: android, ajaxcontroltoolkit

i am trying to make an android app for my school. this is the [web site](https://obs.ankara.edu.tr/login.aspx) of my school. the captcha images source something like https://obs.ankara.edu.tr/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?type=rca&isc=false&guid=247583ef-bfad-4cfe-82d1-8ae8902b07ae so i can not display this source on imageview. how can i display this captcha image?

Answer (score 1):

Try this project to get an idea:

[A very easy to use, minimal options, on-device Captcha system for Android applications](https://github.com/floydfix/Android-Easy-Captcha)

Comment: i am afraid to you miss understand me. i don't need generate new captcha image. i just trying to make a noneoffical app for my school. so i am using jsoup to parse html and display web site content on the app. however i can not display that captcha image of this [web site](https://obs.ankara.edu.tr/login.aspx).